# Let type in a for in loop

Tags: swift, constants, let

I'm playing around with Swift.
Why is it possible to declare `let` type in a for loop? As far as I know, `let` means constant, so I'm confused.

```
    func returnPossibleTips() -> [Int : Double] {
        let possibleTipsInferred = [0.15, 0.18, 0.20]
        //let possibleTipsExplicit:[Double] = [0.15, 0.18, 0.20]

        var retval = Dictionary<Int, Double>()
        for possibleTip in possibleTipsInferred {
            let inPct = Int(possibleTip * 100)
            retval[inPct] = calcTipWithTipPct(possibleTip)
        }

    return retval

    }
```

Comment: `let` defines a scope based constant - in your case in the for-loop. It basically means that assigning a new value to variable declared with "let" is not possible.

Comment: Think of it in terms of `var` is `Mutable` and `let` is `Immutable` instead of a constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lifespan of the `inPct` constant is only during the loop iteration since it is block scoped:

```
for i in 1...5 {
    let x = 5
}
println(x) // compile error - Use of unresolved identifier x
```

In every iteration `inPct` refers to a new variable. You can not assign to any of the `inPct`s in any iteration since they were declared with `let`:

```
for i in 1...5 {
    let x = 5
    x = 6 // compile error
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In basic words when you define: `let possibleTipsInferred = [0.15, 0.18, 0.20]` it means that `possibleTipsInferred` is *read-only* variable. You can iterate over it but not change it.

Furthermore, in Swift you **can't** write:

```
let a:Int?
a = 5      // compile ERROR
```

because `a` has the value `nil`, and you can't change it.

---

in a `for..in` loop, each iteration `i` is *recreated* and receives a new instance per loop.

Therefore you can make it constant and write `let`.

Answer (score 0):

The for loop executes a series of statements so each time we loop through we are in a new "scope." This is very similar to how C handles for loops.

Each time we run through the for loop the stack constant is freed so we can reassign the value of **inPct**.

If we had predeclared a variable outside of the for loop and given it a value we would update the variable's value each time we ran through the for loop.

Here's a link to the docs for for loops in swift:[Control Flow](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html)